# Why can we rewrite regression model this way?

Tags: regression

Reading the "All of statistics" ([PDF](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~wainer/cursos/1s2013/ml/livro.pdf)), on p. 89 (6.2 Parametric and Nonparametric Models) author states:

---

We call $r(x) = E(Y|X = x)$ the regression function.

...

Regression models are sometimes written as:

$ Y = r(X) + \epsilon$

where $E(\epsilon) = 0$. We can always rewrite a regression model this way. To see this, define $\epsilon = Y - r(X)$ and hence $Y = Y + r(X) - r(X) = r(X) + \epsilon$. Moreover $E(\epsilon) = EE(\epsilon|X) = E(E(Y - r(X))|X) =  E(E(Y|X) - r(X)) = E(r(X) - r(X)) = 0.$

---

First, I don't understand how we can write $Y = r(X) + \epsilon$ from the definition above... If $r(x)$ (with *small* x) is a conditional expectation, $E(Y|X=x)$, how does it lead to $Y=r(X) + \epsilon$?

Second, I don't understand what is being shown here... why do we need to show that $E(r(X) - r(X)) = 0$ or $Y = r(X) + \epsilon$? I'm just confused. Any general explanation/advice is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: $\epsilon$ has to satisfy the stronger property $E(\epsilon \mid X) = 0$ for the "you can always rewrite" claim to make sense. The idea of the proof is exactly as above. Is this what confuses you?